# How to create desktop shortcut in Ubuntu 22.04 Xorg? or quick launch "favorite"

Tags: 22.04, xorg

How do I create desktop shortcuts in Ubuntu 22.04 Xorg?

Environment:

```
$ echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
ubuntu-xorg
$ echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
ubuntu:GNOME
```

I think `/home/USERNAME/.local/share/applications` is related but I don't know what to put there (that folder is currently empty).